# swift styling searchbar minimal cancel button and horizon left

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, swift5

**i want to change searchbar cancel button image or change background color
and i need horizontally left**

i already tried like this

```
if let btn = mSearchBar.value(forKey: "cancelButton") as? UIButton {
    btn.backgroundColor = .red  
}
```

but its not work

thanks

[image]

Comment: Try the solution. Hopefully, it will work for you. 
You can change the *MyImage* to whatever the image you want also you can change the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 5**

```
@IBOutlet private weak var searchbar: UISearchBar!{
        didSet{
            if let searchTextfield = self.searchbar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField , let clearButton = searchTextfield.value(forKey: "_clearButton")as? UIButton {
                
                clearButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "cross_vector_icon"), for: .normal)
                
            }
             
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: hi thanks for replay, i got message  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'  ,  this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _clearButton.'

Comment: almost as yours, i think the problem is  forkey: _clearButton ,  i need setting this key somewhere?

Comment: try now I changed the variables name.
I tested on my side and it is working. This supposed to work on your side as well.

Comment: hi Rashid, do you know how to horizontally , i need  padding right,  i tried clearButton.frame = CGRect(-50, 0, 24, 24) but not work

Comment: i got the solve like this SearchBar.setPositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: -20, vertical: 0), for: .clear)

Comment: You can try something like 
```clearButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 50)
clearButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode(rawValue: 1)!
```

But I think it's not a good idea